# using querySelector in vue/test-utils

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

For testing, if a list is correctly rendered from an array prop I need to loop through the created items and see if inside data are ok. But I can't use `querySelectorAll`.

The problem is I can't use `wrapper.findAll` or `wrapper.findAllComponents` because they doesn't give me an array so I can use `forEach`.

```js
<li
  v-for="({ duration, name, description }, index) in works"
  :key="index"
  class="works__item"
>
  <span class="works__duration">{{ duration }}</span>
  <div class="works__infos">
    <strong class="works__name">{{ name }}</strong>
    <span class="works__description">{{ description }}</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

```js
import { mount, config } from "@vue/test-utils";

/**
 * Main component
 */
import Works from '../Works.vue';


config.mocks.$t = key => key

describe('Works', () => {
  it('renders correctly with props', () => {

    /**
     * Defining mock data.
     * -----------------------------------
     */
    const mockData = [
      {
        duration: '2:00',
        name: 'Work 1',
        description: 'Description of work 1'
      },
      {
        duration: '3:30',
        name: 'Work 2',
        description: 'Description of work 2'
      }
    ];

    /**
     * set mock data to the only prop
     * that this component has: work.
     * -----------------------------------
     */
    const wrapper = mount(Works,
      { propsData: { works: mockData },
      attachTo: document.body
    })

    /**
     * Check if the component is rendered.
     * -----------------------------------
     */
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)

    /**
     * Check the list
     * -----------------------------------
     */
    const items = wrapper.findAll('.works__item') //findAll give me WrapperArray but it's not array and it's object!
    const items2 = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.works__item')
    console.log({ items });

  })
})
```

Comment: Hi @ari-shojaei. `findAll()` and `getAll()` should return an array of `DOMWrapper` [per the docs](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#findall). That's what I'm getting back.

Can you confirm the items are rendering by logging the html? `console.log(wrapper.html())`. Also note: you're using `propsData` but the current version of the test-utils expects `props` - [see the migration guide](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/migration/#propsdata-is-now-props).

Answer (score 0):

You can access each element found by `const items = wrapper.findAll('.works__item');`  with `items.at(0)`, `items.at(1)`, etc...

Considering your `mockData` is a proper `Array`, you can do something like:

```
const items = wrapper.findAll('.works__item');
mockData.forEach((mockEntry, index) => {
  expect(items.at(index).text()).toInclude(mockEntry.description);
});
```